# Segfault on bare bones embedded Python?

Tags: python, c

The following C program that uses Python.h:

```
$ cat > test.c

#include <python3.7/Python.h>

int main() {
  Py_Initialize();
  Py_CompileString("foo", "bar", 0);
  Py_Finalize();
}

^D
```

...has a segfault:

```
$ gcc test.c -lpython3.7m
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Debugging with gdb it crashes in:

```
PyParser_AddToken () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems more like C++ than C.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Problem occurs in both C and C++.  Updated to C version.

Comment: The Python library is intended to create Python modules, not programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `start` value is supposed to be `Py_eval_input`, `Py_file_input`, or `Py_single_input`, not `0`.